# How to use Lingua::EN::Ngram for multiple files

Tags: perl, n-gram

I am implementing a naive Bayesian classification algorithm. In my training set I have a number of abstracts in separate files. I want to use N-gram in order to get the term frequency weight, but the code is not taking multiple files.

I edited my code, and now the error I am getting is
`cant call method tscore on an undefined value`. To check this, I printed `@ngrams` and it is showing me junk values like `hash0*29G45` or something like that.

```
  #!c:\perl\bin\perl.exe -w

  use warnings;

  use Algorithm::NaiveBayes;
  use Lingua::EN::Splitter qw(words);
  use Lingua::StopWords qw(getStopWords);
  use Lingua::Stem;
  use Algorithm::NaiveBayes;
  use Lingua::EN::Ngram;
  use Data::Dumper;
  use Text::Ngram;
  use PPI::Tokenizer;
  use Text::English;
  use Text::TFIDF;
  use File::Slurp;

  my $pos_file  = 'D:\aminoacids';
  my $neg_file  = 'D:\others';
  my $test_file = 'D:\testfiles';
  my @vectors   = ();

  my $categorizer = Algorithm::NaiveBayes->new;

  my @files = <$pos_file/*>;
  my @ngrams;
  for my $filename (@files) {

    open(FH, $filename);

    my $ngram = Lingua::EN::Ngram->new($filename);

    my $tscore = $ngram->tscore;

    foreach (sort { $$tscore{$b} <=> $$tscore{$a} } keys %$tscore) {
      print "$$tscore{ $_ }\t" . "$_\n";
    }

    my $trigrams = $ngram->ngram(2);

    foreach my $trigram (sort { $$trigrams{$b} <=> $$trigrams{$a} } keys %$trigrams) {
      print $$trigrams{$trigram}, "\t$trigram\n";
    }

    my %positive;

    $positive{$_}++ for @files;

    $categorizer->add_instance(
      attributes => \%positive,
      label      => 'positive'
    );
  }

  close FH;
```

Comment: Being more specific would be nice - "The code does not take multiple files" leaves me guessing somewhat - do you mean the call to ngram or are you unable to open a list of files? I answered both below ( I think ;) ). Please post error messages if you still have problems. Definitely happy you are using strict and warnings!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions ,yes i am opening multiples the data is read by my code, till the stemming the code is working fine. when i am trying to parse these stemmed words which are stored in an @stems to Lingua::EN::Ngram.. it is giving me errors

Comment: this Lingua::En::Ngram is not taking arrays as an input ... i have multiple files in a folder which i stored in an array , i am not getting how to parse them for ngram in order to calculate the word frequency... your help is appreciated thanks

Comment: That is why I suggested to call ngram for each file, which is what the ( now corrected ) map does.

Comment: I corrected as you suggested i edited the code in my section can you please take a look i also mentioned the error... Thanks once again

Comment: not sure Lingua::EN::Ngram is getting the file right. Try the for loop instead and capture the error message like `my $ngram = Lingua::EN::Ngram( $filename ) or die $!;`. You may have to either give it a full filepath or `chdir( $dirname )` first.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the code formatting, but your code as written will not run. It looks like it's missing the `}` that closes the first `foreach` loop, but since (due to the inconsistent indentation) it's not clear *where* you have that `}`, I couldn't add it in myself. Please edit your question to include the actual code you're using. (Tip: After pasting in some code, select it and press `Ctrl+K` to automatically indent it by four spaces.)

Comment: I have tidied up your Perl code (again - it looks like others have already done it for you before but you removed the change) as it was really awful to read. But it seems odd that you have removed the best part of your program, that you were actually congratulated on, the `use strict`. Hacking around Perl code in the hope that something you change will make it work is no way to do debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `<$pos_file/*>` should work fine ( thanks @borodir ), still, here is an alternative so as to not mess up the history.
Try

```
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
```

and then

```
 while (my $filename = readdir(DIR)) {

    open ( my $fh, $filename );

    # work with filehandle

    close $fh;

}

closedir DIR;
```

If called in list context, readdir should give you a list of files:

```
my @filenames = readdir(DIR);
# you could call that function you wanted to call with this list, file would need to be 
# opened still, though
```

Another point:

If you want to pass a reference to an array, do it like so:

```
function( list => \@stems );
# thus, your ngram line should probably rather be

my $ngram = Lingua::EN::Ngram->new (file => \@stems );
```

However, the docs for Lingua::EN::Ngram only talk about scalar for file and so on, it does not seem to expect an array for input. ( Exception being the 'intersection' method )

So you would have to put it in a loop and cycle through, or use map

```
my @ngrams = map{ Lingua::EN::Ngram->new( file => $_ ) }@filenames
```

Seems unnecessary to open in filehandle first, Ngram does that by itself.

If you prefer a loop:

```
my @ngrams;
for my $filename ( @filenames ){ 
   push @ngrams, Lingua::EN::Ngram->new( file => $filename );
}
```

I think now I got what you actually want to do.

get the tscore: you wrote `$tscore = $ngram->tscore`, but $ngram is not defined anymore.

Not sure how to get the tscore for a single word. ( "significance of word in text" ) kind of indicates a text.

Thus: make an ngram not for each word, but either for each sentence or each file.
Then you can determine the t-score of that word in that sentence or file ( text ).

```
for my $filename ( @files ){
   my $ngram = Lingua::EN::Ngram->new( file => $filename );

   my $tscore = $ngram->tscore(); 
   # tscore returns a hash reference. Keys are bigrams, values are tscores
   # now you can do with the tscore what you like. Note that for arbitrary length,
   # tscore will not work. This you would have to do yourself.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried doing first to open files using openDir the error I am getting is "Use of uninitialzed value at ngram.pm". second when i tried using this "my @ngrams = map{ Lingua::EN::Ngram->new( file => $filename ) }@filenames" it is giving me junk values like array 7089 hence this line is not taking my files... any further suggestions please

Comment: my bad: map should of course have $_, not $filename, corrected in answer

Comment: the "use of uninitialized value at ngram.pm" error is too unspecific, though it may have referred to that line. Please include the line of the error, then I may be able to help

Comment: Not sure ngram can do what you want. It can get you ngrams for arbitrary length, but only tscore for bigrams ( see http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-Ngram/lib/Lingua/EN/Ngram.pm#new%28_file_=%3E_$scalar_%29 ). So you might want to use ngram(), and calculate tscore for non-bigrams yourself

Comment: if i add this line my $ngram = Lingua::EN::Ngram->new( $filename ); it shows me the error this method new can only take text or file as an input . Although i am parsing a file into it .

Comment: have you tried giving it a filename OR a file handle? The docs seem to indicate a filename is sufficient, but perhaps it wants a file handle. Btw, this is beginning to feel like I am debugging your program. I will not.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand your last comment Text google ? I wanted the opedir code but the error is with the Lingua new object it is giving me same error that this method only takes text or file

Comment: Why do you claim that there's a problem with `<$pos_file/*>`?

Comment: Because I made a mistake. I have edited to reflect, sorry. However, the main problem is, by now, that I am no longer sure what exactly he wants to do and gets hung up calling methods in Ngram. I stopped helping at some point :/

Comment: I also made an error with the new() call, which I now corrected and led to his earlier comment. However, it makes my suspicion, that he is merely copy/pasting stuff without trying much himself, grow. Has OP even looked at the documentation? Does he know what he wants to do, exactly?

Comment: Yeah he's not really helping us to assist is he :-/

Comment: I am sorry I am new to Perl :( the problem i am having is with the Ngram method i cannot parse my file contents to it

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions